# Should the 5-Minute-Comment-Editing Timeout restart when editing?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-edits

I don't want to discuss why there is a timeout for editing comments. This has been done numerous times.

However, when I start editing before this deadline, shouldn't the edit go through and be submitted?

Moreover, when I start and finish editing before the deadline, shouldn't the timeout restart from zero?

Comment: "Comment be accepted"? What is this exactly?

Comment: The "system" refuses or rejects the comment if the timeout is expired. Otherwise it "accepts" it. How would you phrase it?

Comment: You mean you want the 5 minutes timer to start ticking only when you start editing? Anyway, "shouldn't the edit go through and be submitted" is more clear. "Accept" has special meaning in SE which makes it confusing when used like that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm using your suggestion now. Sorry for the confusion.
And yes, that was the reasoning.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of [Allow 5 minutes for editing a comment since last edit rather than the creation time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313339/allow-5-minutes-for-editing-a-comment-since-last-edit-rather-than-the-creation-t).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: if you don't like your comment and can't edit it, delete it and repost it.

> However, when I start editing before this deadline, shouldn't the edit go through and be submitted?

No, a potential avenue for abuse would be to start editing your comment and leave your browser open indefinitely.

> Moreover, when I start and finish editing before the deadline, shouldn't the timeout restart from zero?

Then, when I keep on editing my comment every 5 minutes (even if it's a hardly visible change), I'll always be able to edit it, opening up additional possibilities for abuse.

---

<sub>(Examples of abuse would be user A using unfriendly language, which is then edited out once the other user B involved in the 'discussion' replies with unfriendly language; bystanders would be tricked into thinking that user B started the unfriendliness. Only ♦ moderators are able to see a comment's revision history.)</sub>